# Real Analysis objective question.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

[image]

I don’t know exactly how to solve it but my attempt is as follows

$$f’(x)=\sin^4(2g(x))$$ So function is differentiable as composition of two differentiable function is differentiablity . Now it has infinitely many zeroes because of sin(x) has infinity many zero . Please suggest. Thank you .

Comment: $f'(x)=\sin^4\big(2g(x)\big)g'(x)$

Comment: option d is correct

Comment: Yes i got the point thank you very much ...

Comment: Yes we will get zeros

Comment: Please replace the image of text by actual text, making it accessible to people using screen readers etc.

Comment: @Christoph ok sir will replace it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the $\mathscr{chain \ rule}$ and the $\mathrm{FTC}$ here.

If $f(x) = \int_0^{g(x)} \sin^4(2t)dt$, then $f(x) = h(g(x))$ where $h(u) = \int_0^u \sin^4(2t)dt$.

Thus, $f'(x) = h'(g(x))g'(x)$. But $h'(u) = \sin^4(2u)$ by FTC, so:
$$
f'(x) = \sin^4(2g(x))g'(x)
$$

---

Since $g$ is differentiable, it is continuous, and since it is continuous, it has the intermediate value property. Since $g$ is unbounded, it is easy to see that for large enough $N$, the quantities $\{n\pi : n \in \mathbb N , n > N\}$ will lie in the range of $g$. For $n > N$, let $x_n$ be such that $g(x_n) = n\pi$. From above, $f'(x_n) = 0$. Thus $f'$ in fact has infinitely many zeros.